# Jsoup unclosed tag issue

Tags: java, html, kotlin, jsoup, scrape

i have this html and i want to parse it

Code below

```html
<div class="info">
<strong>uno</strong>
<p>gang . boni</p>
<p>4.1 ★ <span>18+</span></p>
</div>
```

here is my code

```
val ce= doc2.select("div [class='columns is-multiline'] p:eq(2)")

println(ce)
```

and its output are this

```
<p>4.1 ★ <span>18+</span></p>
```

but i want the output to be only the 4.1 how to do that? i tried to do first but it give
same thing.

EDIT:

```kotlin
 val ComboImageUrls: Elements = doc2.select("div [class='columns is-multiline'] img[src]")
    val p = doc2.select("div [class='columns is-multiline'] p:eq(2)").first()



    val ce: String = (p.childNode(0) as TextNode).text()

    ComboImageUrls.forEachIndexed { index, movieItem ->
        `is`++
        val Final = ce
        println(Final)

        }
```

here is the code and its output are this

```
3.7 ★ 
3.7 ★ 
3.7 ★ 
3.7 ★ 
3.7 ★
```

which is not what I want. I can do this already but this is not what I want since its duplicating the result, it should give different results like 4.1 3.1 2.1 4.5 3.3 etc etc

and if I use substring in a loop it will simple limit to the first element and will make the loop not function properly.

Comment: It looks like your selector is picking `<p>4.1 ★ <span>18+</span></p>` element and text in that element represents precisely `4.1 ★ 18+`. If you want to only get first part of that `String` then you can do it via String methods like `split` `substring` etc. For instance if you know that it will always be in form `digit dot digit` (so 3 characters) you can use `String value = ce.text().substring(0,3);`.

Comment: check the edit i made and thanks in advance

Comment: I am not Kotlin dev so I am not sure what your code is supposed to do, but from what I see `forEachIndexed` is simply printing `Final` which holds `ce` and `ce` doesn't change here so it would be no wonder you are getting same results. In Java code which would print all ratings can probably look something like `doc2.select("div [class='columns is-multiline'] p:eq(2)").forEach(element -> System.out.println(element.text().substring(0,3));`.

Comment: when i add index to the loop it simple will show an error
        val Final = ce[index]

here is its output
3
.
7
 
★
 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 6
 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
 at WdwdKt.main(wdwd.kt:20)
 at WdwdKt.main(wdwd.kt)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to separate node text from its inner elements:

```kotlin
val cssQueryResult: Elements = Jsoup.parse(q).select("div p:eq(2)")
val p: Element = cssQueryResult.first()
val ce: String = (p.childNode(0) as TextNode).text() // will be equal to '4.1 ★ '
```

Further crop down to '4.1' should be done by means of pure Kotlin.
Depending on variance of parsing results it could be some regex or just simple `ce.substringBeforeLast('★').trim()`

Comment: please check the edit i made and thank you so much for replying to my issue

Comment: to iterate over multiple <p> elements returned in cssQueryResult don't take `first()` element, use [collections operations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collection-operations.html): `cssQueryResult.map { p: Element -> (p.childNode(0) as TextNode).text() }.forEach { println(it) }`

Comment: val p = doc2.select("div [class='columns is-multiline'] p:eq(2)")
    { p: Element -> (p.childNode(0) as TextNode).text() }.forEach { println() }
    println(p)

its not working

Comment: val p = doc2.select("div [class='columns is-multiline'] p:eq(2)").toString().substringBeforeLast('★').trim()
    println(p) does not change anything since it output this
<p>4.7 ★ <span>18+</span></p>
<p>3.3 ★ <span>18+</span></p>
<p>4.7 ★ <span>18+</span></p>